# Servlet está respondendo mas o ajax não reflete a resposta

Tags: ajax, post, servlet

Bom dia,

Eu tenho um formulário simples no qual eu faço submit via ajax, então meu servlet pega esse resultado e da uma resposta, a partir da resposta o ajax irá fazer algo. Eu consigo ver a resposta no navegador, mas não recebo o resultado no ajax.

**JSP:**

```
`
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>



<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/lib/js/jquery-3_2_1_min_js.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="POST" ID="form1" >
        <%-- <%= request.getAttribute( "answer" ) --%>
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
        E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
        Address: <input type="text" name="address" /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="record" />
    </form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form1").on("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("tried to submit the form");
        $.ajax({
            url: "/QualidadeWeb/testando",
            method: "POST",
            //async: false,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            succes: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                console.log("it worked");
            },  
            error: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                console.log("didn't work");
            }
        });
    });
});


</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`

**Servlet:**

```
`
package controllers;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class addContatoServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException{
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        RequestDispatcher rd;
        rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/View/adiciona-contato.jsp");
        System.out.println("testando GET 444");
        try{
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        System.out.println("Testando Post 1234");

        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); 
        out.write("the contact's name is: " + name);
    }
}

`
```

**Como podem ver a resposta funciona**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Porém meu ajax não captura a resposta no console.log, parece que o ajax se perde no meio do caminho:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele só chega até o primeiro console.log, faz o post e depois não faz mais nada, o que poderia ser?

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Tem certeza que `e.preventDefault();`está correto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao que parece o problema é um typo, no seu código está escrito succes:

```
succes: function(data){
```

mas deveria ser **success** (com ss):

```
success: function(data){
```

Lembre de conferir esses detalhes [na documentação](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: Você está correto, era um typo mesmo! Muito Obrigado!!